# multiple services with same self-signed certificate

Tags: .net, wcf, certificate, monitoring

I've got a WCF intranet application I'm working on that will have 150 clients controlled/monitored by a control application.  Is it kosher to create a self-signed certificate and install this same certificate on each of the 150 clients?

I want security between the client and server but will not have authentication support from a domain controller et al.

Any pitfalls in using the same certificate on all these clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pitfall is you won't really be able to distinguish between them unless they're passing some other form of identity along with the request. Plus, if one of them is compromised, you essentially have to shut your entire service off because they all use the same certificate. IMHO you want to create a client certificate per partner to avoid these problems.

The question I have though is, why aren't you just using transport security (i.e. SSL) instead of message security if all you care about is securing the communication and not providing identity?

Comment: Drew, I think using transport security is OK, but don't I still need a certificate?  In a workgroup scenario, don't I still need the certificate or can I get away with Windows ClientCredentialType?

Comment: Yes, but you'll only need a single certificate on the server side. Your clients don't need a cert because they will create a one-off key with your service using the SSL protocol. Now, the only catch here is that if you're creating your server certificate using your own custom CA, your clients WILL need a copy of your CA's public certificate and will need to trust it on their side.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks Drew.  I think that's pretty clean, as I need to install the management service on each of the clients anyways.

Answer (score 1):

If the certificate is compromised, you will need to revoke it, generate a new one, and install it on every machine.  If each machine had their own, you would only need to revoke the one that can no longer be trusted, generate a new one, then install once.

Answer (score 0):

absolutely not. Websites use the same certificate for thousands/millions of users. Only the server will be able to decrypt the information of each client.

Comment: He's talking about client certificates, not server certificates.